# Why are my forms not working after .htaccess URL rewrite?

Tags: forms, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I copied the below code from some other posts. It successfully helped me to stripped the .php extension from the URL. However, after implementing this, my forms are no longer working. I have forms that are posting like `<form method='post' action='login.php' ...`. Now it is not sending the data to the location when I submit the form. I realize that if I change the `action='login.php'` to `action='login'`, the forms will work again. But there are a number of pages that contain forms posting to different locations in my website, and I do not want to change so many of them manually. So I wouold like to know why the data are not posting as expected and how can I solve the problem. Thank you!

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://localhost/domainname/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://localhost/domainname/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://localhost/domainname/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this rule on top **before other rules** to skip all POST requests from rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: Thank you! But why does it work? Isn't the original data also posting to login.php? Where would it go to if I did not add the line?

Comment: `POST` requests shouldn't be redirected otherwise all the POST data will be lost. This rule just skips all POST requests.

Comment: not working.. When I Hit button, it redirects to the index page

Comment: Works for OP, your problem might be different. Go ahead and create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I want to redirect user_login.php to seo friendly url like /user-login with post form data and this worked for me.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/user_login\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ user-login [QSA,R=301]
RewriteRule ^user-login$ user_login.php [QSA,L]
```

In view file

```
<form action="<?php $siteurl;?>/user-login" method="post" id="user_login">
```